# What is the text which has no p label parsed in css model?

Tags: html, css

There are only one difference between html1 and html2.
There are only more 7 characters(that is to say one pair of p lable:`<p><>/p>`) in html2 than in html1.
For html1 :

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
#content{
  width:873px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
#content_left{
  float:left;
  width:398px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content_right{
  float:left;
  width:471px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}    
</style>    
<body>
<div id="content">i am here
  <div id="content_left">content_left
  </div>
  <div id="content_right">content_right
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The html1 was parsed in firefox as the following.
[image]

For html2:

```
<html>
<style type="text/css">
#content{
  width:873px;
  height:400px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
#content_left{
  float:left;
  width:398px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}
#content_right{
  float:left;
  width:471px;
  height:300px;
  border:1px solid red;
}    
</style>   
<body>
<div id="content"><p>i am here</p>
  <div id="content_left">content_left
  </div>
  <div id="content_right">content_right
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The html2 was parsed in firefox as the following.
[image]

Now it is clear that for html2:
1.div content contains three son elements:p lable which contain text `i am here`,div content_left,content_right. They are parent_son relationship in structure.

2.p lable and content_left and content_right are brother relationship in structure.

It is clear html2 was parsed that way by firefox.

Let's analyse html1,no p lable for the text `i am here`.
What the text `i am here` is be parsed by  firefox?
What is the relationship between `i am here` and content_left and content_right?
Why html1 was parsed that way by firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text without p tag treated as `display:inline`. If you add `<p> .. </p>` it is `display:block` So, it's behavior is like that in image.

If you add `display:inline` to p it will look same as first html.

```
p {
    display: inline;
}
```

[Fiddle with `display:inline` in p](https://jsfiddle.net/1pbxuzs3/1/)

Comment: One problem on html1 remains,why inline element such as text `i am here`  was put at the right of div content_left?Why it was pushed beside content_left?Why content_left was first parsed?

Comment: @it_is_a_literature `#content_left` is `float:left` So, it is display to left. To check try removing `float:left` from `#content_left`. Or add `float: left;` to `<p>` tag in my given fiddle in answer.